# Comma Delimiter CSV Import as Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a very simple csv file called detail.csv that contains data like below:

```
Name,Town
John,NY
Charlie,LA
```

I tried to import it using the usual way as

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'path', sep = ',')
```

It usually works when the separation is ;

What did I do wrong? I have been browsing this around the internet, but unable to get the answer.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: This should work. Note that comma is the default separator.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: no error, but the data frame is not separated. It stays as it is with comma (just like the original csv file).

Comment: strange, but also interesting. can you post your output here in the format you get from pandas?

Comment: It looks like your file is not created properly. Same code works for me. When I try to print the dataframe, I can see it in proper way it is expected. Can you try creating your file correctly and make sure no endline characters are present in the file? I tried this: `df = pd.read_csv("demo.csv", sep=',')`

Comment: the output is just the same like the input, with additional index 0 and 1.
@CodeHunter yeah, i think it should be the data source that has the problem, not the code itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing an actual path.  You're passing in a raw string value called `path`.  You should remove the quotes:

`df = pd.read_csv(path, sep = ',')`

Also, you can try to use `delimiter`, instead of `sep`

Comment: hallo, sorry for the confusion. I had no problem with the import, the problem lies with the imported data frame still has comma and not separated. thanks

Comment: i also tried using delimiter, it gave the same result (not able to clear out comma and make the separation)

Comment: What operating system are you doing this on?  Maybe there's an issue in your carriage return?